# Intermittent NPM Build Errors for Angular Libraries - ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod 'dist/acme/library/bundles/acme-library.umd.min.js.map'

Tags: angular, npm, build, angular-cli-v8

We have set of angular libraries which we build and publish to artifactory in our build servers.

Intermittently (like 1 in 50 builds), the build fails with below error.
`ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod 'dist/acme/library/bundles/acme-library.umd.min.js.map'`

This happens completely randomly.  Our builds build everything for the product - in includes C libraries, Java Projects, Angular Projects, etc.  The whole source is checked out from Perforce, and source code is checked out in NFS mount directory, and checkedout source and build out is available for each build via NFS mounted directory.

**If anyone can suggest why an error like below can happen, that will be of immense help?**  It seems to be complaining about a file that should have got created just moments ago during the ng build.

```
Building Angular Package
Building entry point '@acme/library'
Cleaning build directory
Rendering Stylesheets
Rendering Templates
Compiling TypeScript sources through ngc
Bundling to FESM15
'QueryList' is imported from external module '@angular/core' but never used
'ClrWizard' is imported from external module '@clr/angular' but never used
Bundling to FESM5
Bundling to UMD
No name was provided for external module '@clr/angular' in options.globals ??? guessing 'angular'
Minifying UMD bundle
WARN: Side effects in initialization of unused variable Mb [0:745,12]
WARN: Dropping duplicated definition of variable Lc [0:1101,24]
WARN: Dropping duplicated definition of variable Mc [0:1102,24]
WARN: Dropping duplicated definition of variable Nc [0:1103,29]
WARN: Side effects in initialization of unused variable Ie [0:1647,12]
Relocating source maps
Copying staged files

BUILD ERROR
ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod 'dist/acme/library/bundles/acme-library.umd.min.js.map'
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod 'dist/acme/library/bundles/acme-library.umd.min.js.map'

An unhandled exception occurred: ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod 'dist/acme/library/bundles/acme-library.umd.min.js.map'
See "/tmp/ng-Hje1zE/angular-errors.log" for further details.
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! @acme/acme-ui@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.12345 build:acme:feature:library: `ng build acme-library`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @acme/acme-ui@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.12345 build:acme:feature:library script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-03-24T21_30_49_058Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Did you try to disable Ivy?

Comment: We are not using ivy

Comment: It sounds very much like NFS has cached its state, and hasn't invalidated it after the "relocate source maps" step. E.g. here folks seem to describe similar symptoms: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/219354

Comment: Agree with @amakhrov, npm really thrashes the disk during install/build, so trying to do this across an NFS mount is unlikely to work.